# Error running theano.test() - ImportError: DLL load failed: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed

Tags: python, windows, dll, theano, theano-cuda

I'm trying to get theano up and running on a Windows 10 (x64) machine.

I've installed Python from the WinPython distribution, which comes with theano already running. But after installing CUDA 8.0.44 and MingW, I constantly get the following errors when running the simple script

```
import theano
theano.test()
```

Note that I had several warnings before, that I already solved (e.g. by installing missing packages from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/). But this error gives me no usable information. The really weird thing is, that the module-name is not given anywhere that theano is missing.

```
theano.gof.opt: ERROR: Optimization failure due to: constant_folding
theano.gof.opt: ERROR: node: DimShuffle{x,x}(TensorConstant{1.0})
theano.gof.opt: ERROR: TRACEBACK:
theano.gof.opt: ERROR: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Programmieren\WinPython-64bit-3.5.2.2\python-3.5.2.amd64\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\opt.py", line 1772, in process_node
    replacements = lopt.transform(node)
  File "C:\Programmieren\WinPython-64bit-3.5.2.2\python-3.5.2.amd64\lib\site-packages\theano\tensor\opt.py", line 5825, in constant_folding
    no_recycling=[])
  File "C:\Programmieren\WinPython-64bit-3.5.2.2\python-3.5.2.amd64\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\op.py", line 970, in make_thunk
    no_recycling)
  File "C:\Programmieren\WinPython-64bit-3.5.2.2\python-3.5.2.amd64\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\op.py", line 879, in make_c_thunk
    output_storage=node_output_storage)
  File "C:\Programmieren\WinPython-64bit-3.5.2.2\python-3.5.2.amd64\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\cc.py", line 1200, in make_thunk
    keep_lock=keep_lock)
  File "C:\Programmieren\WinPython-64bit-3.5.2.2\python-3.5.2.amd64\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\cc.py", line 1143, in __compile__
    keep_lock=keep_lock)
  File "C:\Programmieren\WinPython-64bit-3.5.2.2\python-3.5.2.amd64\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\cc.py", line 1595, in cthunk_factory
    key=key, lnk=self, keep_lock=keep_lock)
  File "C:\Programmieren\WinPython-64bit-3.5.2.2\python-3.5.2.amd64\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\cmodule.py", line 1142, in module_from_key
    module = lnk.compile_cmodule(location)
  File "C:\Programmieren\WinPython-64bit-3.5.2.2\python-3.5.2.amd64\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\cc.py", line 1506, in compile_cmodule
    preargs=preargs)
  File "C:\Programmieren\WinPython-64bit-3.5.2.2\python-3.5.2.amd64\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\cmodule.py", line 2213, in compile_str
    return dlimport(lib_filename)
  File "C:\Programmieren\WinPython-64bit-3.5.2.2\python-3.5.2.amd64\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\cmodule.py", line 299, in dlimport
    rval = __import__(module_name, {}, {}, [module_name])
ImportError: DLL load failed: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
```

Potentially related posts are [Test Optimization failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24402213/theano-test-optimization-failure-due-to-constant-folding-on-ubuntu) and [Installing theano on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34508431/installing-theano-on-windows-dll-load-failed).

Any ideas how to resolve this or find out what dll is missing?

Comment: To debug: edit the `cmodule.py` file to print *module_name* before `__import__` crashes. Retry and see the module name… Or run `theano.test()` in your debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this issue, by following [this excellent tutorial](https://github.com/philferriere/dlwin) (the only one that actually works and is up to date) for installing Deep Learning Libraries natively on a Windows machine.