# TensorFlow DLL load failed: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I installed and ran TensorFlow on my PC. When i ran it on this error appeared in jupyter notebook. I tried to reinstall Anaconda with Python 3.6 many times but I always get the same error. I tried to install a new operating system 
and install Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015 but there was no improvement. 
i also see [this url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41000780/error-running-theano-test-importerror-dll-load-failed-a-dynamic-link-libra) but it tells me to install Visual Studio 2015 with some features. I install Visual Studio 2015 but it did not help.

Thanks in advance

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py in swig_import_helper()
     13         try:
---> 14             return importlib.import_module(mname)
     15         except ImportError:

C:\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py in import_module(name, package)
    125             level += 1
--> 126     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
    127 

C:\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py in _gcd_import(name, package, level)

C:\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py in _find_and_load(name, import_)

C:\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py in _find_and_load_unlocked(name, import_)

C:\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py in _load_unlocked(spec)

C:\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py in module_from_spec(spec)

C:\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap_external.py in create_module(self, spec)

C:\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py in _call_with_frames_removed(f, *args, **kwds)

ImportError: DLL load failed: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py in <module>()
     57 
---> 58   from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
     59   from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import __version__

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py in <module>()
     16             return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')
---> 17     _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
     18     del swig_import_helper

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py in swig_import_helper()
     15         except ImportError:
---> 16             return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')
     17     _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()

C:\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py in import_module(name, package)
    125             level += 1
--> 126     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
    127 

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-d6579f534729> in <module>()
----> 1 import tensorflow

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py in <module>()
     22 
     23 # pylint: disable=wildcard-import
---> 24 from tensorflow.python import *  # pylint: disable=redefined-builtin
     25 # pylint: enable=wildcard-import
     26 

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py in <module>()
     47 import numpy as np
     48 
---> 49 from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
     50 
     51 # Protocol buffers

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py in <module>()
     72 for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
     73 above this error message when asking for help.""" % traceback.format_exc()
---> 74   raise ImportError(msg)
     75 
     76 # pylint: enable=wildcard-import,g-import-not-at-top,unused-import,line-too-long

ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 14, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module(mname)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 658, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 571, in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 922, in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: DLL load failed: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 17, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 16, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

​